# What does this icon represent on my iPhone XS?

Tags: iphone

After updating my iPhone XS to iOS 16.2 this icon has appeared in the top right of the screen.

[image]

It appears to be an icon of an iPhone with an arrow pointing down towards either the charging port or home button. Of course this model doesn't have a home button which is somewhat strange.

I cannot find it listed among the status icons on [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/iphone/iphef7bb57dc/ios)

I've tried restarting the phone and it still remains. This feels like a glitch since the icon is not properly aligned with the others.